# Checking the ID in the specified range of numbers

Tags: php, range

I have a table containing 10 million file links, each file has its own unique ID. I want to save every 10,000 files in one folder.

This is the ID of the files:

```
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
10000000
```

This is my range of numbers:

```
0
10000
20000
30000
40000
50000
.
.
.
10000000
```

Now how can I determine the range by getting each ID?

For example, if the ID of the file is 5000, it should be placed in folder 0. If the ID is 19000, it should be placed in the 10000 folder

```
id    ----------> folder
5000  ----------> 0
19000 ----------> 10000
21000 ----------> 20000
```

I want this work to be done with PHP language

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? You have "links" in the database, but where are the files and where do they need to go?

Comment: The files are in torrent and I want to download them and save them in different folders on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using basic function `floor`:

```
<?php
function getFolder(int $id) {
    return  floor($id/10000) * 10000;
}
```

https://phpize.online/s/AU